# What IFS should I use in my BASH for loop if my input command arguments are multiple lines?

Tags: bash, for-loop, delimiter, ifs, pcregrep

I want to store each single, complete, multiline result of a pcregrep into a variable for each iteration of a for loop.

Ex:

```
for a in $(pcregrep -Moh 'regex_that_spans_multiple_lines'); do
blah
blah
done
```

However, I'm not sure what IFS I should use which would properly recognize each separate pcregrep result so I can store it into the variable (one result per iteration).

I'm also open to hear other round-about means of accomplishing the goal (even if it doesn't involve IFS)

Here are some sample results that I'd be working with:

Result 1:

```
new PDO(
                                $connectionString,
                                $this->options['user'],
                                $this->options['password'],
                                $this->options['driverOptions']
                        );
```

Result 2:

```
mysqli_connect(
                        $this->options['host'], $this->options['user'], $this->options['password'], null, $this->options['port'], $this->options['socket']
                );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will be better served storing the results in an *array* (or temp file). Bash input is *line-oriented*. `IFS` is the *Internal Field Separator*, it controls *word-splitting*, it has no effect on multi-line control.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. As far as I can tell, there's no special delimiter between results. The results are simply mixed together.

Comment: What separates each multiline result from `pcregrep` in the output?